# Django Iterating over Many to Many Objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My main problem is that my code never goes into the for loop though within the debugger I can see that hardware exists. The for loop gets just skipped and I can´t figure out why this is the case.

Models:

```
class Hardware(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()

class Bundle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    devices = models.ManyToManyField(Hardware)

class BundleForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Bundle
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'devices')
        labels = {
            'name': _('Bundlename'),
            'description': _('Beschreibung des Bundle'),
            'devices': _('Hardware im Bundle')
            }
```

Views:

```
elif request.method == 'POST' and 'newbundle' in request.POST:
    form = BundleForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        bundle = form.save(commit=False)
        bundle.save()

        for hardware in bundle.devices.all():
            print(hardware)

        messages.success(request, 'Erfolg! Die Daten wurden erfolgreich gespeichert.')
        return redirect('/knowledgeeditor/bundle/', {'messages': messages})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not about iterating many-to-many fields, but saving them.

The [modelforms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) has this to say about using `commit=False` with a many-to-many field:

> Another side effect of using `commit=False` is seen when your model has a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a many-to-many relation and you specify `commit=False` when you save a form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the many-to-many relation. This is because it isn’t possible to save many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using `commit=False`, Django adds a `save_m2m()` method to your ModelForm subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the form, you can invoke `save_m2m()` to save the many-to-many form data.

As noted there, you could use `save_m2m()` to save the field, but instead of doing that you should ask yourself *why* you are using commit=False here at all. There is no reason to do so, so you should omit that parameter and the subsequent separate save, and just let the form save itself in one go.

Comment: I intended to use the object directly to perform some other actions. So to save me some time and DB operation, I used commit=false. I was not anticipating the implication with save_m2m(). But it fixed the problem, thank you.